# Android - onCreateView is called onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with two fragments. In this one fragment is replaced by the other. I have added both fragments to the backstack.

```
  @Override
public void showGatherIntentions() {

    gatherIntentionView = GatherIntentionsFragment.newInstance(GatherIntentionContract.INTENTION_OPTION_NONE);
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate (GATHER_INTENTIONS, 0);


    if (!fragmentPopped) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(0, 0, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right)
                .replace(R.id.contentFrame, (Fragment) gatherIntentionView)
                .addToBackStack(GATHER_INTENTIONS)
                .commit();
        currentPosition++;
    }
}
```

code for replacing first fragment

```
 @Override
public void showCollectPreferences() {
    collectPreferencesView = CollectPreferencesFragment.newInstance(CollectPreferencesContract.DEFAULT_OPTION);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left,
                    R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right)
            .replace(R.id.contentFrame, (Fragment) collectPreferencesView)
            .addToBackStack(COLLECT_PREFERENCES)
            .commit();
    currentPosition++;
}
```

code for replacing the second one

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
        finish();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
        currentPosition--;
    }
}
```

State is saved for second fragment but not for first fragment i.e whenever i am on second fragment and press back button its onCreateView method is called .

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you will press back and current fragment comes using replace fragment NOT ADD FRAGMENT then onCreateView will be called. if you use add fragment instead then it will not be called.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i have also tried add instead of replace and its still the same. I am unable to save the state of the first fragment(selected list item).

Comment: try by passing null in .addToBackStack(null) instead any name

Comment: @DivyaJaisawal  `.addToBackStack(null) `

Comment: tried .addToBackStack(null) . onCreateView is still getting called :(

Comment: it  will call always if you replace fragment.

Comment: Trick is do stuff in oncreate if you dont want to be invoked when coming back

Comment: getting null pointer exception since i have binded my views onCreateView